# Scrolling PDF documents in Safari is too sensitive?

Tags: safari, pdf, macos

In Safari, I use two finger dragging with my trackpad (on a MacBook) to scroll through websites. I've noticed that whenever I try viewing a PDF document, (i.e. the URL in the address bar ends with `.pdf`) the scrolling sensitivity is very different than the normal Safari scrolling sensitivity. It scrolls way too fast (i.e. it's too sensitive).

My guess is that it's a problem with the Adobe Reader plugin which doesn't implement scrolling using the same algorithm as Safari's. Is there any way to fix this? What about using a different plugin for PDF documents besides Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari can open PDFs using Preview without the need for Adobe Reader to be installed. In my experience, Preview in Safari is faster and smoother than Adobe's Reader plug-in.

See [this question for how to disable the Adobe plug-in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/how-to-disable-acrobat-reader-in-safari).