# AdobePDFViewerNPAPI shows up in Mission Control

Tags: pdf, mission-control

When I open a PDF document in Safari and then go into Mission control, I see a window with 
different kinds of artifacts (e.g. horizontal black lines on a white background) and it's titled **AdobePDFViewerNPAPI (Safari internet plug-in)**. This window is probably related to the Adobe Reader plug-in that Safari uses. Is there any way to have this window not show up in Mission Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to just use a different PDF plugin for Safari. There are instructions on how to do that [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14747/how-to-disable-acrobat-reader-in-safari).

Answer (score 0):

deleting the plugins from the library worked for me:

http://forums.macworld.com/index.php?/topic/146648-hide-adobepdfviewernpapi-in-mission-control-how/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.